# VS2019 linux cannot find additional dependencies

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++, visual-studio-2019

I am doing a remote C++ build from VS2019 to a machine with Centos. When I input the library to the option  additional dependencies, the vs2019 always shows  *****g++ : error : libTest.a: No such file or directory***** , the file ***libTest.a*** is a library I wrote to test my solution.

Comment: `When I input the library` How have you done it?

Comment: Provide more details like screenshot of you build environment and how are you including this library and the path where the library is set in your environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should properly configure you VSLinux environment.

First, add additional include directory on **Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional include directory**. Add paths of directories for additional header files for your library.

Second, add additional library directory on **Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional library directory**. Add directories where your static/shared libraries are.

Third, put your name of libraries on **Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Library dependency**. Add the name of your library. Remember, you should remove prefix lib and the extension of the library.

The exact name of the option may differ since I'm not using VS2019 in English.